# Beamer: 2 columns in part of page

Tags: beamer

I would like to produce a slide in which there is more flexibility in the blocking.

```
+-----------------------------------------------+
+ Block A                                       +
+ Item                                          + 
+ item                                          +
+-----------------------------------------------+
+--------------+ +------------------------------+
+ Block B      + + Figure using includegraphics +
+              + +                              +  
+--------------+ +------------------------------+
```

I've tried various combinations of columns and block, but cannot get the desired result.

Comment: Can you provide one of those trials here such that potential answerers can use it as a template?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: If my answer satisfies your needs could you consider to accept it? As a new user, I would courteously suggest you for the future to upvote all answers you find useful, including those to others' questions and to check/accept the best answers to your own questions by clicking the green tick on the left-hand side of the answer. This will help the community.

Answer (score 6):

You just have to use the `columns` in combination with some adjustment in defining the picture size:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{mwe} % for dummy image
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Title}
\begin{block}{The block title}
\begin{itemize}
\item a
\item b
\end{itemize}
\end{block}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{0.345\textwidth}
\begin{exampleblock}{Another block title}
\begin{itemize}
\item a
\item b
\end{itemize}
\end{exampleblock}
\end{column}%
\begin{column}{0.645\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=0.6\textheight]{example-image}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Notes:

- define the width of the two columns such that the sum of two does not exceed `\textwidth` (in my example it is a bit less than that value to not have warnings);
- set the image size in the right way: you can use again `\textwidth` for the width since this value actually correspond to the width of the column, but be careful on the height.

Comment: The block near the image does not have the same height of the image: this ultimately is an example, but in your presentation you probably will fit the block with some more text. The block height depends on the content, so it may look better when you will apply the solution to your presentation.

Comment: Yes, that seemed to work. I was using the version of \column{size}. Using \begin{column}{size} blah blah \end{column} works as desired. \column{size} does not work as expected.

Comment: Giving the option `[T]` to `{columnes}` can top-align the `{exampleblock}` and the image

Comment: @KevinC: yes, it's right, but since we can't predict how much text should fit the block I preferred let things not top-aligned: this will let the block expand in both directions which IMHO has a better look.